# How implement correct custom exception handler?

Tags: spring-boot, exception

I want to throw my errors in the right places with a specific error code. But I cannot understand why this approach does not work for me.

```
@ControllerAdvice
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class ApiExceptionsHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

@ExceptionHandler(ApiException.class)
protected ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> handleApiException(ApiException ex) {
    return ResponseEntity
            .status(ex.getStatus())
            .body(ex.getError());
}


@Getter
public class ApiException extends Exception {

private final ErrorResponse error;
private final int status;

public ApiException(String message) {
    super(message);
    this.error = new ErrorResponse(message);
    this.status = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value();
}

}

    @Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ErrorResponse {
    private final String errorMessage;
}




@PostMapping(value = "/card")
public void cardAttributes()
        throws  ApiException {
    throw new ApiException("sad");
}
```

I want to get 400 error code and description in postman, but

```
{
"timestamp": "2021-05-20T21:02:28.455+00:00",
"status": 500,
"error": "Internal Server Error",
"message": "",
"path": "/card"
}
```

my pom

```
    <dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
  <version>3.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
```

Instead of 500 errors and the body, I want to get my own error and the error text that I wrote, but that doesn't work ..

Comment: What is the package of the controller where `/card` is located and what is the package of `ApiExceptionsHandler`? By default Controller class must be located in same package (or in its sub-packages) as ApiExceptionsHandler. Otherwise you have to explicitly declare packages (like `@ControllerAdvice("my.controller.pkg")`)

Comment: it worked. make your answer a separate post pliz. Спасибо)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that your controller (with `/card` endpoint) is located in the same package (or in its sub-package) with `ApiExceptionsHandler`.

Otherwise you have to explicitly declare controller package(s), like following:

```java
@ControllerAdvice("my.controller.pkg")
```

Comment: it worked for me only if I moved the handler to the folder with the controller, but from another folder with the annotation it didn't work and I need the second option

Comment: @СамирШахмурадлы i've just checked it out, working as intended. For example my controller is located at "company.web.rest" and ControllerAdvice is located at "company.web.dummy" so they are neither in same packages nor in one's another sub-packages. Then 1) I explicitly write `@ControllerAdvice("company.web.rest")` and consume endpoint with invalid POST data (like non-existent ID) in order to cause exception -- ControllerAdvice is invoked (error response is formatted as I expect).

Comment: Then 2) I explicitly write `@ControllerAdvice("company.web.nonexistent")` and consume same endpoint with invalid POST data -- ControllerAdvice is NOT invoked (default error response formatting) since it's not configured to handle  target package `company.web.nonexistent`. So there is something wrong with your packages configuration

Comment: I am sorry, it was my component scan problem. Thanks